# Number of points over a curve over finite fields

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Artin's conjecture is that for $f$ a separable polynomial irreducible modulo $p$ of degree 3, the equation $y^2 \equiv f(x) \mod p$ has a number of solutions $n$ satisfying
$$n = p + O(\sqrt{p}).$$

I would like to understand better this $p$: is there a way to see that there are generically these $p$ expected solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $k$ distinct values of $x$ where $f(x)=0$ which contributes $k$ points when $y=0$. On the other hand there are $p-k$ values of $x$ where $f(x) \ne 0$. Now we can roughly estimate that half of the time $f(x)$ is a perfect square for these $p-k$ values. This gives us $\frac{p-k}{2}$ solutions. Except since $y$ and $-y$ both contribute a solution we really have twice that many solutions. In total that means we have,

$$k+2*\frac{p-k}{2} = p$$

solutions naively speaking.

Comment: This was exactly the kind of heuristics I was searching for. The argument does not hold anymore for $y^d = f(x)$, because we do not know if all the $d$-th roots of unity are in the base field, right?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose we could refine the guess in a precise way along this lines of thinking involving either forcing congruences on $p$ or looking at what elements in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ have order dividing $\gcd(d, p-1)$ to alter our counting formula. Also, don't forget to mark the question as answered.